# Can functions be stored as fields? Is this a good approach for callbacks?

Tags: ios, swift, class, swift2

I am looking for something where I can pass a function as a parameter in swift for my class.

This is my current code.

```
import Foundation

class StatusProgress{
    static var queue = "dispatch_get_main_queue" //which queue you want it to run under.
    static var priority = 0 //priority in the queue
    static var cancelCode = {}
    static var runCode = {}
}
```

I'm not sure if this will work.  **Is this the proper way to define that my class will take functions as part of its parameters?** For example cancelCode and runCode are supposed to be functions that can be passed in to be ran.

The doesn't seem to throw any errors.

I'm doing this to make a progress class which will take arbitrary code and run it on a custom progress window.

The alternative method to what I'm doing might be to make a property of this require a class that must adhere to a protocol possibly.  Not sure how that would work yet though.

Comment: Keep in mind that Functions are not Methods.

Comment: Good point, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can declare them the way that you did, if the methods will take no parameters and not return anything.

Out of curiosity, though, why are your properties `static`?

Comment: They are static since I will only ever have one progress window in my case, so since I'm not really making an instance, I figured this might be best way to organize it.  Also on iOS you can only ever really show one progress window at a time.

Comment: what if sometimes they will have parameters?

Comment: @JosephAstrahan probably, you would like that nobody can override it in a subclass (static are not able to be overridden) ... if defined as class var, than it is possible. by the way, static var f:(Int)->Int = { return $0 } is also valid , so you can define it to have any valid 'function type' and 'redefine it later, if you want'

Comment: interesting, I remember studying the $0 part, I forgot what that represented again, was that the parameter? So the function takes integer parameter and returns int is what is saying.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan function in swift is the same as closure and you can assign its value to any let or var, as you want. in you case with my example you can call it as StatusProgress.f(someIntValue) and it will return it. You can use the same approach for instance properties, as well.